# Manually launching remote kernel results local process frozen

Tags: remote-access

I'm trying to launch a Linux (Ubuntu latest) machine as a slave of my local PC (Windows 8). Both machine have Mathematica 9 installed. However, I'm behind a router, so I think it's a little more complicated. I found out that mathematica uses port ranging from 58000 to 59000 (at least at the moment I ran it, because actually it just asks the system for one, which increases constantly), so I forwarded the router's port 58000~59000 to my PC. Following [this FAQ](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3659), I went ahead and set up my local kernel, and start to listen. The prompted window said

> Link created on: 58917@104.xx.xxx.xxx,58918@104.xx.xxx.xxx

so I went ahead, opened up putty, connected to the remote machine, started mathematica kernel using `math`, and ran

```
$ParentLink = LinkConnect["58917@104.xx.xxx.xxx,58918@104.xx.xxx.xxx", LinkProtocol->"TCPIP"]
```

Immediately, on my local machine, a message box pops up that says:

```
Out[1]= LinkObject[58917@104.xx.xxx.xxx,58918@104.xx.xxx.xxx, 60, 1]
```

which I suppose means that  the connection is successful. However, on my local PC, the entire mathematica process freezes and becomes "not responding".

[image: screenshot]

Has anyone ever encountered the same problem? Why is that?

---

**Update**: After a long *long* time, the message box finally printed something new:

[image]

Not a good news huh? Again what might be happending?